# How to check if a timestamp is within a range using a dynamic array

Tags: vba, excel, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a code that identifies what time period or 'session' a timestamp falls into and am having some problems. I have an array that varies depending the the number of user inputs (see below example):

arrTemp (1,1) = "8:00"
arrTemp (1,2) = "12:00"
arrTemp (2,1) = "13:00"
arrTemp (2,2) = "14:00"
arrTemp (n,1) = ""
arrTemp (n,2) = ""

Where the times in the first and second columns are the start and end times of the sessions respectively.

I then have a list of times in column C. I want the a 1 to be displayed in column D if the time in C falls between 8:00 and 12:00 (ie the start and end time of the first row in the array), a 2 if it falls between the times in the second row and so on.

If the time does not fall between any start and end times in the array I want "Outside Session" to be written in column C.

I have the following code.

```
    For Each Cel In Range(.Range("C2"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
        For ic = 1 To UBound(arrTemp)
            If Cel >= CDate(arrTemp(ic, 1)) And Cel <= CDate(arrTemp(ic, 2)) Then
                    Cel.Offset(, 1) = ic

                    Exit For

            ElseIf Cel > UBound(arrTemp) Then
                    Cel.Offset(, 1).Value = "Outside Session"
                        MsgBox "One or more lines are outside a session timeslot. Consider revising the session timeslots.", vbExclamation, "Warning"

            End If

        Next
    Next
```

However, I have noticed that sometimes the timeslot is not always correct, the "Outside Session" does not display and the MsgBox item does not display.

Anyone with a brilliant bit of insight that can tell me where I have gone wrong and why it may not always be working?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an example of data that returns incorrect reults?
Your ElseIf statement is never called. You compare the cell (i.e. the time) with the number of elements in your array. What (I'm guessing) you want to do is compare the time with the last element in your array, something like `ElseIf Cel > arrTemp(Ubound(arrTemp, 2))`

Comment: how does your _"list of times in column C"_ look like? Is every cell content a `String` value or a `Date` one?

Comment: There is a really interesting VBA function called Partition https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek4702k8(v=vs.90).aspx which does something similar but not exact to your requirement, you might want to see if you can base a solution on that.

Comment: @JanB No I don't have an example of the incorrect results. It only occurs on one dataset and I don't have the dataset that did that at the moment. I see what you mean regarding the ElseIf. I will give that a try tonight.

Comment: @user3598756 The cell content is 12:17:30
 so I believe it is a Date structure.

Answer (score 1):

**edited** after OP's clarification `arrTemp` values are not *full* hours as per original example

his you could try this

```
Dim exitLoop As Boolean

With Range("C2", Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
    For Each cel In .Cells
        ic = 0
        Do
            ic = ic + 1
            If arrTemp(ic, 1) = "" Then Exit Do
            exitLoop = CDate(cel) >= CDate(arrTemp(ic, 1)) And CDate(cel) <= Hour(arrTemp(ic, 2))
        Loop While ic < UBound(arrTemp) And Not exitLoop

        cel.Offset(, 1) = IIf(exitLoop, ic, "Outside Session")
    Next
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Offset(, 1), "Outside Session") > 0 Then MsgBox "One or more lines are outside a session timeslot. Consider revising the session timeslots.", vbExclamation, "Warning"
End With
```

Comment: The Hour function effectively rounds down time values. This works better with the four Hour functions changed to CDate.

Comment: @tlemaster, I adopted `Hour` following OP's example. Should user6661501 give any feedback to this answer and with respect to having `arrTemp` values with "broken" hours then `CDate()`  would be mandatory.

Comment: @user3598756 as I have minutes and seconds in my time the Hour function doesn't quite work. I will try and modify tonight and get back to you.

Comment: @user3598756, unfortunately this doesn't work.  It does show the msgbox "one or more.....", however this happens on every run, even when all the times are within the timeslot.

Comment: in my test it worked. may be our data have different "structure": you may want to add links to show your actual data